# Display admin sidebar into custom post pages if logged

Tags: admin, admin-menu

Is it possible to display the default admin sidebar in a custom post type page (frontend view) if user is logged in, as happens for the admin top bar?
If is possible, how can I do this? Any hint?

Comment: would it not be easier to show the custom post type page inside WP Admin? A lot of code only runs in WP Admin that directly affects the admin navigation so if you get what you want it won't show half the options. Doing it will also involve loading parts of WP Admin on the frontend which is a ***major*** security risk. What's the goal of doing this?

Comment: Thank you @Tom for your answer, I was investigating some ways to keep consistency among pages. I'm working on a private web app, dashboard style, where I need some pages to be on the front end, access is only possible after login. I'm trying to find alternative solutions. Thank you.